# How can I insert "day" first rather than month in TextMode="Date" - ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net

When I select the TextMode ="Date" in my aspTextBox, I need to type first the month (MM/dd/yyyy), but I want to write first the day (dd/MM/yyyy).

Is there a way to perform this??

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() { $( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"}); });
</script>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="date" ClientIDMode="Static" />

or

<asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="date" 
Format="dd-MM-yyyy" runat="server"  </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```